# Extending an S3 generic from an optional package

Tags: r, generics

I have a [package](http://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable) which provides an `as.FlexTable` method for its objects, extending the S3 generic from the `ReporteRs` package. So, my NAMESPACE file, generated by roxygen, has lines:

```
importFrom(ReporteRs,as.FlexTable)
...
S3method(as.FlexTable,huxtable)
...
export(as.FlexTable)
```

I don't much want to put ReporteRs in Imports: in the DESCRIPTION file, because it involves a big external dependency on Java. But, when I put it into Suggests:, `R CMD check` gives me errors like "Namespace dependency not required".

Is there anyway I can extend the generic without making a hard dependency?

Comment: You might get a quicker response at the r-devel list: https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Importing is a hard dependency.
Some people do not import formally but use  `<pkgNamespace>::<obj>`
instead, *and* conditionalize their code on the availability of
that namespace.
I don't recommend that at all, and particularly not for
extending a generic.

I recommend you talk with the maintainer of `ReporteRs`:

1. You could use a common (yet-to-create) very small package say `flexS3generics`
   which provides S3 generics (and S4 if ..) you want to use
   both, and then both you and her/him import from that mini package.
   You'd be both authors of that package.
2. If your package is much smaller (in its footprint, incl
   dependencies) than 'ReporteRs' she/he may agree to import the
   S3 generic from your package instead of the other way around.

Both are clean solutions, and both need some time-coordination when releasing to CRAN,
'1)' being easier: Once the `flexS3generics` is released to
CRAN, change (both) your package(s) to
`importFrom(flexS3generics, as.FlexTable)`  but these changes and CRAN
submissions are then independent of each other.

((Taste: I'd strongly prefer `as.flexTable`  (lowercase "f")))

Comment: I probably ought to know, but who is Martin Maechler? (NB Martin: I'd prefer `as_flextable`, but that ain't my call and the package has been around for 5+ years....)